# how to use random.normalvariate(mu, sigma) when values are in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a this dictionary with the first value being a mean and the second standard deviation

{'Kevin': (100.0, 10.0)}

I need a function to generate a random value using the normal distribution and return the output into a dictionary with the name 'kevin' as a key.

expected output - output may look like this
   {'kevin': 111.52090179040226}

Comment: whats wrong with `new_dict['kevin'] = random.normalvariate(old_dict['kevin'][0], old_dict['kevin'][1])`

Comment: Presumably OP wants to do this for a dict with many entries.  I'd do it with a dictionary comprehension: `new_dict = {k: random.normalvariate(*v) for k,v in old_dict.items()}`.

Comment: How would you write this in a function

Comment: I'm pretty sure with a little bit of effort you could handle writing a function.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the dictionary contents, call the function and put it back in the dictionary